# Javascript Timers not consistent

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I know there has been many topics on Javascript Timers however, my timers are in effect "Doubling" every time my mouse hovers over a div to call a command, they are not consistent.The divs below show the onmouseover event which calls the functions.

```
<div id="Team_Container2"><div id="Image1" onmouseover="area_hover1(this);area_hover2(this)"></div>
<div id="Team_Container2"><div id="Image2" onmouseover="area_hover1(this);area_hover2(this)"></div>



function area_hover1(obj) {
    var interval;
    clearInterval(interval);
    href = $(obj).attr('href');
    url = href.split('#');
    url1 = url[1];
    interval = setInterval(function() {setAreaOver(document.getElementById(url1), 'Seating_Plan_Image_canvas', '0,0,0', '0,0,0', '0.33', 0, 0, 0);}, 1000);
            return;
}

function area_hover2(obj) {
        var interval;
        href = $(obj).attr('href');
        url = href.split('#');
        url1 = url[1];
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function() {setAreaOver(document.getElementById(url1), 'Seating_Plan_Image_canvas', '0,0,0', '0,0,0', '0.0', 0, 0, 0);}, 2000);
        return;
}
```

How could i adjust the timer or merge the two functions into one and perform one "setInterval" after the other one.

I need the area_hover2 set Interval to come like 500 milliseconds after the first Area_hover1 set interval if that makes sense.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks
Aj

Answer (score 1):

Every time you hover over your image, you kick off a new `setInterval`, since your `clearInterval()` command isn't really doing anything. You defined the variable holding the `setInterval()` pointer inside the hover function, so as soon as it exits, that variable is gone. What you need is:

```
var interval; // Defined in global scope
function area_hover1(obj) {
   clearInterval(interval); // Abort any existing hover interval
   // Set up variables
   interval = setInterval(function() { /* doStuff */ }, 1000);
}
```

You may also need to capture the `onMouseOut` event to stop the interval as well, since right now it will keep running even after the mouse is no longer hovering over the element.